# ¿Cómo puedo validar una grid para que no se repita al agregarla una vez?

Tags: extjs

Tengo un combobox, donde escojo un ítem, y ese lo agrego a una grid, pero lo que deseo es que no se pueda agregar el mismo al ya ser agregado la primera vez.

```
onAddClick: function() {
    var me = this,
        combo = me.down('[name=comboboxEventosScoreType]'),
        value = combo.validate();
    if (value === true) {
        var data = combo.valueModels[0].raw,
            grid = me.down('[name=gridEventosScoreType]'),
            rec = new Events.model.grid.ScoreType(data);
        grid.getStore().insert(0, rec);
    }
}
```

La grid:

```
xtype: 'grid',
                name: 'gridEventosScoreType',
                flex: 1,
                layout: 'fit',
                autoScroll: true,
                store: new Ext.data.Store({
                    autoDestroy: true,
                    autoLoad: true,
                    model: 'Events.model.grid.ScoreType',
                    proxy: {
                        data: [],
                        type: 'memory',
                        reader: {
                            type: 'json'
                        }
                    }
                }),
```

Desde ya, gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es recorrer el store antes de agregar el registro con el comando:

```
store.each(function(record,id){
});
```

Y en alli hacer la validacion

Answer (score 0):

Puedes recorrer tus datos mientras los agregas y verificar con algun campo, sea Id, nombre o cualquiera que lo diferencia de los demas y preguntar si existe ya en el grid o no. Tambien es otra opcion que tus datos antes de agregarlos los ordenes, no se de que forma los obtienes (base de datos, agregados por el usuario, consulta a un ws, etc) pero puedes hacer cualquiera de las dos.

```
extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
idProperty:'firstName',
fields: [
    { name: 'Id', type: 'int', defaultValue: 0 },
    { name: 'firstName', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'middleName', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'lastName', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'birthDate', type: 'date' },
    { name: 'address1', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'address2', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'city', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'state', type: 'string' }
],
```

1) Dejo fuente que puede ayudarte!

[Ejemplo](http://www.extjs-tutorial.com/extjs-examples/autoSync-in-extjs-4-grid-example)

2) Misma pregunta tuya en stack over flow [Pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566224/allow-duplicate-ids-to-display-in-a-grid-ext-js)